# List Capacity API in Azure Devops not returning capacity of members who have left the organisation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

When using the List Capacity Rest API to fetch data for previous Iterations the results doesnot include the data of users who have left the organisation. There is no way to get the capacity of the user for that sprint. How can we get the Sprint capacity snapshot of previous iterations?

If we need to calculate the team capacity for previous iteration we need capacity of all users for that iteration.The current API response removes the users who have left the organisation.

List Capacity API :

https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/{iterationId}/capacities?api-version=5.1

Answer (score 0):

The capacity should remains unmodified at the end of the sprint, as the capacity is defined explicitly for each sprint.

Give a try with directly Review capacity charts in Azure DevOps web portal.

As you define tasks and estimate the work, you'll see capacity charts start to fill in for each team member. Capacity bars track the remaining work against the capacity for each team member as well as the entire team.

[image]

1. Go the "Sprints":

[image]

2. Click on the "View options" icon and choose "Work details":

[image]

3. Now you will see it:

[image]

Comment: Yes , @PatrickLu-MSFT the capacity is available in Azure devops. In Devops the capacity is unmodified and I can see the capacity of all users including those who have left the organisation but while fetching the same data using capacity  REST API the response is missing data of the users who have left the organization. I need to use the member capacity in my application

Comment: @Hari As you have pointed out, List Capacity Rest API will not return capacity of members who have left the organization. Sorry for any inconvenience. You may have to manually check the capacity in Azure DevOps and input it in your application.  There is not any parameters could expand the return result.

Comment: my application will be pulling the capacity data for multiple teams and displaying it. I have reported the issue in user forum as well. It will not be feasible to manually input the data  as I'll not be having access to other users project.

Comment: Hi Hari, thanks for your kindly update. But there should not be so many users which leaved your organization and assigned capacity.  You could ask other users project admin to count those specific users. And you only need to do this one time. Since that data will no change. Certainly, we are pleased to listen the solution you got elsewhere. Kindly share it here.

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT I still couldnot find any solution for this. Even if there are only few users who have left the organisation , there will still be many previous sprints that the user was part of . Also they might've had offDays as well. So the data for all sprints before the user left the organisation will not be proper.